# Elegant String to Date (Range) Conversion in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, refactoring, type-conversion

In my database, I have a date field of type varchar(8) that I am using to store date values in the format YYYYMMDD. I am having difficulty creating a simple CR formula to display a date range in the following format:

**October 1, 2012 to October 31, 2012**

Here is my current and very unattractive CR formula:

```
stringvar yYear;
stringvar mMonth;
datevar OrigDate;
numbervar StartDay;
stringvar EndDay;

yYear := Mid ({Command.Date}, 1, 4);

select Mid ({Command.Date}, 5, 2)
case "01": mMonth:= "January"
case "02": mMonth:= "Februry"
case "03": mMonth:= "March"
case "04": mMonth:= "April"
case "05": mMonth:= "May"
case "06": mMonth:= "June"
case "07": mMonth:= "July"
case "08": mMonth:= "August"
case "09": mMonth:= "September"
case "10": mMonth:= "October"
case "11": mMonth:= "November"
case "12": mMonth:= "December";

OrigDate := CDate(ToNumber({Command.Date}[1 to 4]), ToNumber({Command.Date}[5 to 6]), ToNumber({Command.Date}[7 to 8]));
StartDay := ToNumber({Command.Date}[7 to 8]);
EndDay := Mid(ToText(DateSerial(Year(OrigDate), Month(OrigDate) +1, 1-1)), 4, 2);

mMonth + " " + ToText(StartDay, "#") + ", " + yYear + " to " + mMonth + " " + EndDay + ", " + yYear
```

This works but in the spirit of maintainability and good/clean coding practices, I would like to simplify this function if possible.

I am relatively new to writing reports in Crystal so I am hoping that I haven't "re-invented the wheel".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
local numbervar year := tonumber(left({Command.Date},4));
local numbervar month:= tonumber(mid({Command.Date},5,2));
local numbervar day := tonumber(right({Command.Date},2));
local datevar stDate := date(year,month,day);
local datevar endDate := dateserial(year,month+1,day-1); //get last day of month

totext(stDate,"MMMM d, yyyy") + " to " + totext(endDate,"MMMM d, yyyy")
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I knew there had to be a simpler solution. The perils of over-thinking...

Answer (score 0):

A DRYer solution?

Create a custom function:

```
// YYYYMMDD()
// Convert a value in 'YYYYMMDD' to a Date
Function (Stringvar value)

    Date( ToNumber(value[1 to 4]), ToNumber(value[5 to 6]), ToNumber(value[7 to 8]) )
```

Create a formula for the starting date:

```
//{@Starting Date}
YYYYMMDD( {Command.Date} )
```

Create a formula for the ending date:

```
//{@Ending Date}
// find first day of current month, add a month, subtract a day, truncate time
Date( DateAdd("m", 1, Date( Year({@Starting Date}), Month({@Starting Date}), 1) ) - 1 )
```

Embed both formula fields in a text field and format each field as desired (increased flexibility).